# tikz: specify the size of image

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (1.0, 2.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I have the generated image actually range from `(0.0, 0.0)` to `(4.0, 8.0)` (filled with void where there is nothing drawn)?

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]`?

Comment: @campa the rectangle should remain strictly from (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 2.0)

Comment: Do you mean a border around the rectangle? I'm having troubles in understanding what the question is...

Comment: What do you mean by "filled with void where there is nothing drawn"?

Comment: @Viesturs  Please give an explample wich makes more clear what you want to create.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (1.0, 2.0);
  \node [] at (4.0,8.0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The canvas is now the rectangle from (0,0) to (4,8) with just the (0,0) - (1,2) rectangle drew in it.

Comment: With your suggestion the rectangle will be placed at bottom left side of canvas? I suspect, that OP would like to have rectangle in the middle, but who know what OP  like to achieve with this unusual demand ...

Comment: OP did not specify more than "image in range from (0,0) to (4,8)" which is not so specific, so I have interpreted the question in its most literal meaning

Comment: my question is motivated by a series of tikz images of equal size independent what is drawn on them (like equal sheets of paper). From your answer I get the idea.

Comment: I now checked your answer. It appears that drawing an empty node `\node [] at (4.0,8.0) {};` adds a margin to the image.

Comment: In my humble opinion, people in this community would be able to help you more accurately if you expose your problem including every single detail of your requirement  @Viesturs